# DocuSign: Multiple signer recipients not working

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having a problem with the API. I want to have multiple signers in a document but I'm always receiving this error via mail:

> Documents you sent for electronic signature could not be delivered to this email adress

I'm using the example code of Docusign. The mails are valid. Has anyone an idea what could be wrong?

This is the code:

```
<?php
    
    # PHP Quick start example: Send signing request by email.
    # Copyright (c) 2018 by DocuSign, Inc.
    # License: The MIT License -- https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
    
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once('vendor/docusign/esign-client/autoload.php');
    
    function send_document_for_signing(){
        #
        # The document $fileNamePath will be sent to be signed by <signer_name>
    
        # Settings
        # Fill in these constants
        #
        # Obtain an OAuth access token from https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator
        $accessToken = '**ACCESS TOKEN**';
        # Obtain your accountId from demo.docusign.com -- the account id is shown in the drop down on the
        # upper right corner of the screen by your picture or the default picture. 
        $accountId = '**ACCOUNT ID**';
        # Recipient Information:
        # The document you wish to send. Path is relative to the root directory of this repo.
        $fileNamePath = 'demo_documents/World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf';
    
        # The API base_path
        $basePath = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi';
    
        # Constants
        $appPath = getcwd();
    
        #
        # Step 1. The envelope definition is created.
        #         One signHere tab is added.
        #         The document path supplied is relative to the working directory
        #
        # Create the component objects for the envelope definition...
        $contentBytes = file_get_contents($appPath . "/" . $fileNamePath);
        $base64FileContent =  base64_encode ($contentBytes);
    
        # create the DocuSign document object
        $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  
            'document_base64' => $base64FileContent, 
            'name' => 'Example document', # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => '1' # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);
        
        # The signer object
        $signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([ 
            'email' => '**mail1**', 'name' => '**name1**', 'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1",
        ]);
    
        $signer2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
            'email' => '**mail2**', 'name' => '**name2**', 'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2",
        ]);
    
        # DocuSign SignHere field/tab object
        $signHere = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ 
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1', 
            'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147'
        ]);
    
        $signHere2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '2',
            'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '230', 'y_position' => '180'
        ]);
    
        # Add the tabs to the signer object
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $signer->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere2] + [$signHere]]));
    
        # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
        $envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
            'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
            'documents' => [$document], # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
            # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
            'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer] + [$signer2]]),
            'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
        ]);
        
        #
        #  Step 2. Create/send the envelope.
        #
        $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
        $config->setHost($basePath);
        $config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " . $accessToken);
        $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
        $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelopeDefinition);
        return $results;
    };
    
    # Mainline
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        try {
            $results = send_document_for_signing();
            ?>
    <html lang="en">
        <body>
        <h4>Results</h4>
        <p>Status: <?= $results['status'] ?>, Envelope ID: <?= $results['envelope_id'] ?></p>
        </body>
    </html>
            <?php
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            if ($e instanceof DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException) {
                print ("\nDocuSign API error information: \n");
                var_dump ($e->getResponseBody());
            }
        }    
        die();
    }
    # Since it isn't a POST, print the form:
    ?>
    <html lang="en">
        <body>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Send document signature request!"
                    style="width:21em;height:2em;background:#1f32bb;color:white;font:bold 1.5em arial;margin: 3em;"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have a mistake on this line:

```
'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer] + [$signer2]]),
```

try the following

```
 'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer, $signer2]]),
```

Comment: Thank you, that's working! But now the sign here tabs are just working for one signer. I have in the example two sign here tabs for the “recipient_id” 1 and 2 but these fields needs to be signed by the first signer. https://ibb.co/VpdmnSw

Comment: Please ask as a new question. Include the relevant source.